# CRM email router not picking up automated emails

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, email-router

I am using MS Dynamics CRM Email router with MS exchange 2013. When an email comes into exchange for certain queues, the CRM email router picks them up and a custom plugin is fired to deal with the email. This all works fine.

The problem I'm having is for a particular customer. They send out emails via an automated service, the details of which I don't have. These emails never get picked up, as in the plugin doesn't fire.

But if the same customer sends an email manually, the plugin does fire. I can't see any significant difference in the message headers of an email that worked and one that didn't. Anything obvious I should be checking?

Comment: Is that email reaching CRM? Just see spam or junk folders in mailbox/forward mailbox

Comment: It's not reaching CRM no. It's nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Where are you checking the message headers then? Add the sender in mailbox safe sender list & try.

Comment: I'm checking message headers in exchange. Thanks for the input by the way